# How to get and set value/location on vertical scroll bar in SpreadsheetGear control

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am using the `SpreadsheetGear` control. I would like to be able to get the position of the vertical scroll bar so that after a refresh of the control I can return users to the same set of rows they were viewing before the refresh.

The `ScrollPositionChanged` event is working just fine, but I'm not seeing any information in the `WorkbookView` object or the `ScrollPositionChangedEventArgs` object that tells me the current location of the scroll bar.

I'm also not seeing any way to set a value on the vertical scroll bar to reset it's location after the refresh.

I'm sure I'm being thick here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the row position of the top row as you scroll by using the ScrollRow property of the WindowInfo object.

```
int rowPosition = workbookView1.ActiveWorksheet.WindowInfo.ScrollRow;
```

If you want workbookView to return to this position, you can use the Activate() method on a worksheet cell.

```
workbookView1.ActiveWorksheet.Cells[rowPosition, 0].Activate();
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for the answer. I'm looking to set the horizontal scroll position to the same column every time I open a new spreadsheet file. I changed your idea to: ActiveWorksheet.Cells(0, 22).Activate(). This does activate the column (I see it is selected). But the column is not scrolled into position. I tried: WorkbookView1.ActiveWorksheet.WindowInfo.ScrollColumn = 22. That sets column 22 to the left most position in the WorkbookView. But I can't scroll to see columns A-V. Also, I had to do GetLock and ReleaseLock.